# How to get fb like buttons to load last?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a page with a bunch of imgs, these imgs link to their own page.  For each img, I have a like button, with the url to the individual page.

In FF, the imgs load first, but in Chrome, it seems that the like buttons load first.

How can I get the like buttons to load after the page is otherwise loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Since, you didn't posted any code, I can only give you this link to the jQuery command .ready(): http://api.jquery.com/ready/

If you put a function within this command, it will only be executed after every image or other content of the page (or an element) is loaded.

For example you can add the Facebook like button with jquery after the images are loaded like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
       $("#fbPages").children("li").each(
           function(key, val) {
               $(val).html($(val).html() + '...FBLIKEBUTTON...');
           }       
       );    
    }
);
```